# Cannot update allowMembersEditMembership

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, app, client-object-model

I can't seem to update the setting on a group to allow members to edit members. This is my code:

```
function setGroupsMembershipEditingMode(uri) {
  var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
  var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, uri);
  var oWebsite = appContextSite.get_web();

  var groups = oWebsite.get_siteGroups();
  var ownersGroup = groups.getByName('Owners');
  ownersGroup.set_allowMembersEditMembership(true);

  context.load(ownersGroup);
  context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onFailed));

  function onSucceeded() {
    alert("AllowMembersEditMembership = " + ownersGroup.get_allowMembersEditMembership());
    //actually returns true but the setting is not changed!!!

    alert("Done");
  }

  function onFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me with what do I need to put in the `context.load` to get it to work? Thanks?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, whether you already found the answer. But you have to put in

`ownersGroup.update()`

before your `context.load`